# Error occurred during installing VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, installation, ide, failed-installation, visual-studio-2017

I can't install Visual Studio Community 2017 RC

[image]

The log:

> [1a48:0007][2016-12-09T16:08:29] Error 0x80131509:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.VerifyInstallationPath(IServiceProvider
>   services, String installationPath, IInstance instance, IQuery query)
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String
>   destination, CancellationToken token)The specified instance '5d0b6377'
>   cannot be installed to the same location or child directory of
>   existing instance 'f8835dde'.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, does your issue is solved or not?

Answer (score 8):

From https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3379/install-failed-and-cant-reinstal.html:

> Added a solution by David Walker · Nov 20 at 09:52 PM
>
> I searched hard drive and deleted folders that contained the instance
> 'key' - '478ecff' than reran installer.
>
> c:\dir 478ecff /s .. showed me folders to delete/empty.... once I did
> that installer would run again without throwing above error.
>
> Hope this helps someone else.

In your case substitute `478ecff` with your own instance - `f8835dde`

Answer (score 5):

Refer to the error message, you can try to perform a complete uninstall of any existing VS 2017 RC or VS ‘15’ preview if you have installed before.

Firstly, go to Control Panel—Programs and Features and uninstall the existing Microsoft Visual Studio Installer.

Secondly, try to delete the following installed folders: (you can back up those folders before any modification, in case we need to roll back)

1. Go to the folder: %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio and delete the Packages folder
2. Go to the Visual Studio installation folder (normally under %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio) and delete the folders: 2017 or VS15Preview

After that, reboot the computer and re-run the VS 2017 RC installer as administrator again.

Answer (score 1):

I found in below location
1. C:\Users[your account]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ to 
check the folder name start with 15.0_
2. C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages_Instances

if you still have problem, you can have a search in register

hope this can help to find the locaiton quickly

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure to turn off your Antivirus.
Deactivating **McAfee**(Company Policy) solved the Problem for me.
Before that I was getting all kind of errors from the setup, including the one described.